# Stopped using edmx, starting using Code First got this error

Tags: entity-framework, code-first, edmx

So here at work we decided to stop using edmx and starting using Code First mainly because of the issues with merging the edmx file over and over.

Using File -> New Item -> Ado.Net Entity Data Model i've created the models from our existing database, however when running some code i get this errors
I have searched but can't figure out what they are telling first, the 
error lines 324, 343 simply don't exist neither in the class mentioned 
neither on the generated DBContext.

Also should this just work out of the box ...

> ERROR (3015): Problem in Mapping Fragments starting at lines 324, 343:
>   Foreign key constraint
>   'SubModule_SubModulesCurricularUnitsAcademicYears' from table
>   SubModulesCurricularUnitsAcademicYear (ModuleId, SubModuleId) to table
>   SubModule (Id, ModuleId):: Insufficient mapping: Foreign key must be
>   mapped to some AssociationSet or EntitySets participating in a foreign
>   key association on the conceptual side.
>
> ERROR (3015): Problem in Mapping Fragments starting at lines 99, 135: 
>   Foreign key constraint
>   'PlanStudiesCurricularUnit_PlanStudiesCurricularUnitsAcademicYears'
>   from table PlanStudiesCurricularUnitsAcademicYear (PlanStudyId,
>   CurricularUnitId) to table PlanStudiesCurricularUnit
>   (CurricularUnitId, PlanStudyId):: Insufficient mapping: Foreign key
>   must be mapped to some AssociationSet or EntitySets participating in a
>   foreign key association on the conceptual side.

```
  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SubModulesCurricularUnitsAcademicYears] (
    [PlanStudyId]      BIGINT         NOT NULL,
    [CurricularUnitId] BIGINT         NOT NULL,
    [AcademicYearId]   BIGINT         NOT NULL,
    [ModuleId]         BIGINT         NOT NULL,
    [SubModuleId]      BIGINT         NOT NULL,
    [TeacherId]        BIGINT         NOT NULL,

     ....
    CONSTRAINT [PK_SubModulesModulesCurricularUnitsAcademicYear] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PlanStudyId] ASC, [CurricularUnitId] ASC, [AcademicYearId] ASC, [ModuleId] ASC, [SubModuleId] ASC, [TeacherId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_SubModulesModulesCurricularUnitsAcademicYear_AcademicYears] FOREIGN KEY ([AcademicYearId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AcademicYears] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_SubModulesModulesCurricularUnitsAcademicYear_CurricularUnits] FOREIGN KEY ([CurricularUnitId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[CurricularUnits] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_SubModulesModulesCurricularUnitsAcademicYear_PlanStudies] FOREIGN KEY ([PlanStudyId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[PlanStudies] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_SubModulesModulesCurricularUnitsAcademicYear_SubModules] FOREIGN KEY ([SubModuleId], [ModuleId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[SubModules] ([Id], [ModuleId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_SubModulesModulesCurricularUnitsAcademicYear_Users] FOREIGN KEY ([TeacherId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([Id])
);




 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SubModules] (
    [Id]          BIGINT         IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [ModuleId]    BIGINT         NOT NULL,
    [Name]        NVARCHAR (150) NOT NULL,
    [Description] NVARCHAR (100) NULL,
    [Active]      BIT            CONSTRAINT [DF__SubModule__Activ__7A721B0A] DEFAULT ((1)) NOT NULL,
    [Deleted]     BIT            CONSTRAINT [DF_SubModules_Deleted] DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_SubModules] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC, [ModuleId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_SubMudules_Modules] FOREIGN KEY ([ModuleId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Modules] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Generated db context:

```
//onModelCreating only refers to Submodules and SubModulesCurricularUnitsAcademicYears in the following lines
...
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder){
   modelBuilder.Entity<SubModule>()
                .HasMany(e => e.SubModulesCurricularUnitsAcademicYears)
                .WithRequired(e => e.SubModule)
                .HasForeignKey(e => new { e.SubModuleId, e.ModuleId })
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<SubModulesCurricularUnitsAcademicYear>()
                .Property(e => e.ECTS)
                .HasPrecision(5, 2);

}
...
```

Generated poco's

```
public partial class SubModulesCurricularUnitsAcademicYear
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public long PlanStudyId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public long CurricularUnitId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public long AcademicYearId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 3)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public long ModuleId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 4)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public long SubModuleId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 5)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public long TeacherId { get; set; }

    ...

    public virtual AcademicYear AcademicYear { get; set; }

    public virtual CurricularUnit CurricularUnit { get; set; }

    public virtual PlanStudy PlanStudy { get; set; }

    public virtual SubModule SubModule { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}


public partial class SubModule
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public SubModule()
    {
        SubModulesCurricularUnitsAcademicYears = new HashSet<SubModulesCurricularUnitsAcademicYear>();
    }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public long ModuleId { get; set; }

    ...


    public virtual Module Module { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<SubModulesCurricularUnitsAcademicYear> SubModulesCurricularUnitsAcademicYears { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Weird outcome, can there be traces of you'r previous edmx mapping remaining in you'r code that would cause this ?

Comment: what are: - your pk and fk sql definition for tables SubModulesCurricularUnitsAcademicYear and SubModule; - your model for corresponding class; - your Code First configuration for corresponding class; - your expected model.

Comment: @tschmit007 updated the question with the sql

Comment: @AntoinePelletier i think not i've physically deleted the files, and the connection string don't mention any metadata

Comment: I can't see any FK from `SubModulesCurricularUnitsAcademicYears` to `SubModules`. So the fk is probably missing in your model.

Comment: @tschmit007 sry my bad posted wrong sql, its correct now

Comment: Added the model class's generated